# sorting a list of lists in lisp

Tags: list, sorting, lisp

I have a list of lists of this form :

```
testlist((a 22) ( b 2) ( c 5))
```

My goal is to sort the testlist based on the numbers' values (5 first greatest values). Is there a way to achieve this without having to iterate over the list and compare numbers to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ANSI Common Lisp:

```
(sort (copy-list '((a 22) (b 2) (c 5)))  #'< :key #'second)
-> ((B 2) (C 5) (A 22))
```

The `copy-list` is there because `sort` clobbers the input list. We need that because our input list is a literal, but even if it isn't, sometimes you don't want to scramble the original object that you wish to sort.